# Checkbox Array only showing checked values - PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

I have a form with many checkboxes.

ex.

```
...
<input name="dodatkowe[]"  type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input name="dodatkowe[]"  type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input name="dodatkowe[]"  type="checkbox" value="1" />
...
```

I want to have all the checkboxes in the array. Array 'dodatkowe'.

When i checked all checkboxes have:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 )
```

but when i checked example only second I have:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 )
```

I need that, when i check example second checkbox:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 0)
```

Comment: Browsers only submit checked checkboxes, so you will never see values for unchecked checkboxes.

Answer (score 4):

give them indexes so you can reference them specifically...

```
...
<input name="dodatkowe[1]"  type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input name="dodatkowe[2]"  type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input name="dodatkowe[3]"  type="checkbox" value="1" />
...
```

Not sure why you feel you need to see the unchecked values, this can be assumed to be the inverse of the checked values....  Any attempt to do this is a hack, and is unnecessary.

Comment: Possibly, each preceded by a: `<input name="dodatkowe[1]" type="hidden" value=0">` (alter the number after `dodatkowe[` accordingly of course).

Answer (score 2):

If a checkbox isn't checked it won't include it's value into the parameters but the first step would be to give the checkboxes a unique id:

```
<input name="dodatkowe[0]"  type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input name="dodatkowe[1]"  type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input name="dodatkowe[2]"  type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

Then you can use PHP to check is the value is there:

```
$maxfields = 3;
$selectboxes = $_REQUEST['dodatkowe'];
for($i = 0; $i < $maxfields; $i++)
  if(!isset($selectboxes[$i])) $selectboxes[$i] = 0;
```

This will set all non existent fields to 0 and `$selectboxes` should contain the result you are looking for.

Comment: Not sure I like (or would reccomend) directly modifying the `$_REQUEST`... might get confusing, depending on what further processing you need to do with submitted values.

Comment: True... you might want to consider to copy that over to another variable before...